# Wrap unknown count of string using replace

Tags: c#, replace

Sorry for the title, I had a hard time trying to summarize this.

I'd like to replace an unknown number of instances of a string with a wrapper.  So I'd like to replace this:

```
Test with two:\t\t tab characters
```

With this:

```
Test with two:<span class="" style="white-space:pre">\t\t</span> tab characters
```

There could be any number of \t characters in the given string, and in multiple locations.

The reason I'm trying to do this is our software uses Chilkat to sent emails, and if HTML content contains tabs, these are not shown at the receiving end.  When sent, we use \t to represent a tab, and when viewing the source of the received email, the tabs are there, but outside the source they are not:

**Outside Source:**

[image]

**Source:**

[image]

I tested with GMail, and this wraps the tabs:

[image]

[image]

I understand this maybe be a Chilkat issue, but I can't find much help on the topic, but if I can get around it as above, I'm willing to try it.

Comment: You should spend some time learning *regular expressions* (regex), they are exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: Se following webpage : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up using.  The capture group was picking up each repetition individually, and then the replace was only replacing the first found instance, not the entire capture group

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Test with two:\t\t tab characters";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\t)+", "<span class=\"\" style=\"white-space:pre\">$&</span>");
        }
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "Test with two:\t\t tab characters";
            string output = Regex.Replace(input, @"(\t+)", "<span class=\"\" style=\"white-space:pre\">$1</span>");
        }
    }
 }
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks!  I do need to get better with regex.

Comment: Actually this turned out to be incorrect.  I thought it was working, but this was replacing every instance of a tab with the replace value, I only wanted it wrapped once for all tabs that were together.  I've added the code that worked below